# How can I exclude a file from deploy in gcloud?

Tags: google-cloud-storage, google-cloud-platform, gcloud

I have built a Node.js app and what I do to deploy is `cd` into my project's directory and run `gcloud preview app deploy`. This works, but in the files I also have a JSON file which acts like the database for my application, which I do not want updated on the site when I deploy.

I cannot seem to find any way of doing this.

Any idea?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I believe you will want to use the [skip_files](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/config/appref#skip_files) directive in your app.yaml to exclude paths or files you do not want deployed.

Something like:

```
skip_files:
  - ^your_data_dir/.*\.json?
```

Comment: Actually, that `skip_files` link goes to Python 2.7 docs; the Python 3 version says the option is "not supported for Python 3.7", and the Node docs don't even list it.

As mentioned in another answer, the `.gcloudignore` file should be used instead.

Comment: if I have two cloudbuild yaml files in the same directory, can I apply this .gcloudignore to only one of them? possibly can I give it a custom name then import it in the cloudbuild.yaml ?

Answer (score 23):

In this case, a `.gcloudignore` file would help by preventing the upload of any file or directory. The syntax is the same as the `.gitignore` file.

First you could make sure `gcloudignore` is enabled:

```sh
gcloud config list
```

If it is not, then you may enable it:

```sh
gcloud config set gcloudignore/enabled true
```

Some `gcloud` commands like `gcloud functions deploy` may automatically generate a `.gcloudignore` file.

The `.gcloudignore` file **must** reside in the project root folder.

Here is the `.gcloudignore` that is automatically generated by the `gcloud function deploy` command:

```
# This file specifies files that are *not* uploaded to Google Cloud Platform
# using gcloud. It follows the same syntax as .gitignore, with the addition of
# "#!include" directives (which insert the entries of the given .gitignore-style
# file at that point).
#
# For more information, run:
#   $ gcloud topic gcloudignore
#
.gcloudignore
# If you would like to upload your .git directory, .gitignore file or files
# from your .gitignore file, remove the corresponding line
# below:
.git
.gitignore

node_modules
```

This worked fine for me with a NodeJS project with the following structure:

```sh
~/Workspace/my-project $ tree -a
.
├── .idea
│   ├── func-project.iml
│   ├── misc.xml
│   ├── modules.xml
│   ├── vcs.xml
│   └── workspace.xml
├── .gcloudignore
├── index.js
├── package-lock.json
└── package.json
```

In this case, **without** the `.gcloudignore` this is what is deployed:

[image]

And **with** the following `.gcloudignore`:

```
.gcloudignore
.git
.gitignore
.idea
node_modules
package-lock.json
```

This is what is deployed:

[image]

See [more on this](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/topic/gcloudignore).

Comment: The `.gcloudignore` file is 
respect by default if the `gcloudignore/enabled` config is not set, so it doesn't need to be enabled explicitly. See https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/topic/gcloudignore

Comment: @KlemensZleptnig Yes, I have this very same document at the end of my post. Although it is evaluated by default, it can be disabled. That is why I recommend checking the enabled flag status.

Comment: I just wanted to clarify that the default value for it is `true` (because for some people like me it might not be included in the output of `gcloud config list` if it has never been set).

Answer (score 19):

There is skip_files directive in your app.yaml to exclude paths or files you do not want deployed.

But If you are working on a node.js project you would have to use `.gcloudignore` file which will specify which directories to exclude.

> This .gcloudignore would prevent the upload of the node_modules/ directory and any files ending in ~:

```
  node_modules/
  *~
```

Reference to documentation:
1. https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/topic/gcloudignore
2. https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/nodejs/config/appref (search 'skip_files')

Answer (score 1):

In the case for google compute engine run:

```
gcloud config set gcloudignore/enabled true
```

In the case of google app engine:
create a file called `.gcloudignore` in root dir and add the folders or files to be ignored
it acts just like .gitignore