# How to ignore files when running `gcloud app deploy`?

Tags: python, google-app-engine, google-app-engine-python

When I run

```
gcloud app deploy app.yaml
```

which files actually get uploaded?

The project folder contains folders and files such as `.git`, `.git_ignore`, `Makefile` or `venv` that are irrelevant for the deployed application.

How does `gcloud app deploy` decide which files get uploaded?

Comment: related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40805182/see-the-files-that-will-be-deploy-to-google-appengine

Comment: Also: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36751908/how-can-i-exclude-a-file-from-deploy-in-gcloud

Answer (score 45, accepted):

***tl;dr: you should use a `.gcloudignore` file, not `skip_files` in `app.yaml`.***

While the prior two answers make use of `skip_files` in the `app.yaml` file. There is now a `.gcloudignore` that is created when using `gcloud deploy` or `upload` commands. The default will depend on the detected language that you are using but here is automatically created `.gcloudignore` that I found in my Python project:

```
# This file specifies files that are *not* uploaded to Google Cloud Platform 
# using gcloud. It follows the same syntax as .gitignore, with the addition of
# "#!include" directives (which insert the entries of the given .gitignore-style
# file at that point).
#
# For more information, run:
#   $ gcloud topic gcloudignore
#
.gcloudignore
# If you would like to upload your .git directory, .gitignore file or files
# from your .gitignore file, remove the corresponding line
# below: 
.git 
.gitignore

# Python pycache:
__pycache__/
```

**Note**: These commands will not work when both `skip_files` is defined and `.gcloudignore` is present. This is not mentioned in the [skip_files`definition of the`app.yaml` reference](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/config/appref#skip_files).

It seems better to have a globally recognized standard across `gcloud` commands and makes more sense to adopt the `.gcloudignore` versus using the `skip_files` which is only relevant without App Engine. Additionally, it works pretty much like a `.gitignore` file which the reference mentions:

> The syntax of .gcloudignore borrows heavily from that of .gitignore;
>   see https://git-scm.com/docs/gitignore or man gitignore for a full
>   reference.

https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/topic/gcloudignore

Comment: How do you do a dry run of what will be ignored/included? `gcloud meta list-files-for-upload`.

Answer (score 12):

EDIT Aug 2018: Google has since introduced `.gcloudignore`, which is now preferred, see dalanmiller's answer.

---

They're all uploaded, unless you use the `skip_files` instruction in `app.yaml`. Files with a dot like `.git` are ignored by default. If you want to add more, beware that you're overriding these defaults and almost certainly want to keep them around.

```
skip_files:
  - ^Makefile$
  - ^venv$
  # Defaults
  - ^(.*/)?#.*#$
  - ^(.*/)?.*~$
  - ^(.*/)?.*\.py[co]$
  - ^(.*/)?.*/RCS/.*$
  - ^(.*/)?\..*$
```

Note also that they are uploaded to *different places* if you use a static handler. Static files are sent to a CDN and are not available to your language run time (although there are ways around that, too).

Make sure to read the docs:

https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/config/appref#skip_files

Comment: Thanks. Is there a way to `ls` which files got uploaded? So I can retrofit that `skip_files` setting.

Comment: Not sure. They keep adding features, I think there are some things available in the cloud console that allow you to inspect deployed code, but I've never used them.

Comment: @Chris Careful with that example - it overwrites the `skip_files` defaults, which can cause problems, see: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46311440/appengine-no-module-named-pyasn1-compat-binary?noredirect=1#comment79607866_46311440

Comment: Bonus question: I'm using a "flexible environment". So my static files get deployed to the same computing instance and not CDN, right? Is that fine? Or should I take action?

Comment: This covers it: https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/flexible/python/serving-static-files

Answer (score 2):

> How does gcloud app deploy decide which files get uploaded?

It doesn't. It uploads everything by default. As mentioned in another response you can use the [skip_files](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/config/appref#skip_files) section in app.yaml as follows:

```
skip_files:
- ^(.*/)?#.*#$
- ^(.*/)?.*~$
- ^(.*/)?.*\.py[co]$
- ^(.*/)?.*/RCS/.*$
- ^(.*/)?\..*$
- ^(.*/)?\.bak$
- ^\.idea$
- ^\.git$
```

You can also use the `--verbosity` param to see what files are being deployed, i.e. `gcloud app deploy app.yaml --verbosity=debug` or `gcloud app deploy app.yaml --verbosity=info` [per docs](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/).