# Google App Engine Deploying files is too big

Tags: node.js, google-cloud-platform

I'm using GCP app Engine to my node api project.

When I deploy it, file size was usually 2MB, but it is 661MB now.

I think the previous version didn't include node_modules folder size.

But it included node_modules size now.....

How can I change back?

This is the image for my instance version.
https://i.stack.imgur.com/HIVOw.png

Comment: You probably changed something, there should be a `.cloudignore` file which contains upload exceptions. Can you please share your build/deploy script with us?

Comment: Possible duplicate https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46434270/how-to-ignore-files-when-running-gcloud-app-deploy/52022563

Comment: I added "node_modules/" in ".gcloudignore" file.

Answer (score 2):

Google didn't assume node files for the deployed version.
therefore my deployed version size is usually small size such as 2MB.

But they changed the policy, so in deployed version, file size includes all of the module files.